# How do I flip images with bounding box coordinates?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, object-detection, yolo

I have images with bounding box coordinates in yolo format. Coordinates are saved in text files. I want to flip all the images and want new coordinate text files for those images. So a loop would iterate over the folder, load image and annotation text file, flip the image, generate new annotation text file and save both the image and annotation file in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to change only x-axis use this equ: X_new = width -x -1
Note: Name operation in my function can be fliplr or flip up down

```
enter code here  def flip_anotation(my_path, name_jpg, name_operation, axis=1):
# Handle with flip data
file_data = []
# open file and read the content in a list
with open(os.path.join(my_path, name_jpg + '.txt'), 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        currentLine = line[:-1]
        data = currentLine.split(" ")
        # add item to the list
        file_data.append(data)

    # Change X_center Fliplr
    for i in file_data:
        i[axis] = str(1 - float(i[axis]) - 1 / img.shape[1])[0:8]


    # Write back to the file
    f = open(os.path.join(my_path, name_jpg + name_operation + '.txt'), 'w')
    for i in file_data:
        res = ""
        for j in i:
            res += j + " "
        f.write(res[:-1]) # Save all but ignore from the least " "
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```